# I can not deploy tutorial based project to Google Application Engine

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm new to GAE and I'm using GAE tutorial https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating 
Changes are minimal (only names of classes) and all is working locally with localhost:8080 with mvn appengine:devserver command. pom.xml file is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<groupId>com.marceniuk</groupId>
<artifactId>decisiontreegae</artifactId>

<properties>
    <app.id>328809469980</app.id>
    <app.version>1</app.version>
    <appengine.version>1.9.24</appengine.version>
    <gcloud.plugin.version>0.9.58.v20150505</gcloud.plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<prerequisites>
    <maven>3.1.0</maven>
</prerequisites>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
<artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
<version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                        <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                <webResources>
                    <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                <version>${app.version}</version>
                <!-- Comment in the below snippet to bind to all IPs instead of just localhost -->
                <!-- address>0.0.0.0</address>
                <port>8080</port -->
                <!-- Comment in the below snippet to enable local debugging with a remote debugger
                     like those included with Eclipse or IntelliJ -->
                <!-- jvmFlags>
                  <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag>
                </jvmFlags -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
          <artifactId>gcloud-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${gcloud.plugin.version}</version>
          <configuration>
            <set_default>true</set_default>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run with command 
mvn appengine:update
and fill in code from GAE I get

```
  Unable to update:
 com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL:   
 https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create? 
  app_id=328809469980&version=1&
  404 Not Found
  This application does not exist (app_id=u'328809469980').

at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:336)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:287)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:266)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.LoggingClientDeploySender.send(LoggingClientDeploySender.java:47)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:1168)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.beginTransaction(AppVersionUpload.java:781)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.uploadFilesTransaction(AppVersionUpload.java:223)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:200)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:572)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:58)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$UpdateAction.execute(AppCfg.java:1440)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:345)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:222)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:126)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:122)
at com.google.appengine.appcfg.AbstractAppCfgMojo.executeAppCfgCommand(AbstractAppCfgMojo.java:250)
at com.google.appengine.appcfg.Update.execute(Update.java:32)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.
 main(Launcher.java:356)com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AdminException:  
 Unable to update app: Error posting to URL: 
 https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?
 app_id=328809469980&version=1&
 404 Not Found
 This application does not exist (app_id=u'328809469980').

at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:578)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:58)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$UpdateAction.execute(AppCfg.java:1440)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.executeAction(AppCfg.java:345)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:222)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.<init>(AppCfg.java:126)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg.main(AppCfg.java:122)
at com.google.appengine.appcfg.AbstractAppCfgMojo.executeAppCfgCommand(AbstractAppCfgMojo.java:250)
at com.google.appengine.appcfg.Update.execute(Update.java:32)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
  Caused by: com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/create?app_id=328809469980&version=1&
  404 Not Found
  This application does not exist (app_id=u'328809469980').

at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:336)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:287)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:266)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.LoggingClientDeploySender.send(LoggingClientDeploySender.java:47)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:1168)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.beginTransaction(AppVersionUpload.java:781)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.uploadFilesTransaction(AppVersionUpload.java:223)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:200)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:572)
... 30 more
```

I've followed instructions using only command-line and text editor. By the way it was maven embedded in my eclipse. Maybe it caused the problem.

Please help me. I'd be thankfull for any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a project at https://console.developers.google.com/project.

Once your project is created, replace `328809469980` with the project id of your newly created project and try to deploy again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, koma! Yes, it helped  me. It was my mistake with project id